# I have data and set limits. I want to determine how much data is outside of the limits and by how much

Tags: excel-formula

I'd like to determine how far out of tolerance some test data is.
If I have the actual data in D4 (Value 3.7), the lower limit in F4 (value 2.5) and the upper limit in G4 (value 3.5)
I'd like to generate a number indicating how far out each value is in a separate window in J4.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `IF`. Something like `=IF(D4>G4, D4/G4-1, IF(D4<F4, D4/F4-1, ""))` will give you the percentage over/under the limit, if any.

If you just want the nominal over/under, use `=IF(D4>G4, D4-G4, IF(D4<F4, D4-F4, ""))`

Comment: That works (thanks), but the percentages aren't useful in this application.
I just need to know how far out numerically the data is from passing tolerances.

Comment: @RiderRon then just use subtraction instead of division. See my edit

Comment: D4 is the data, F is the lower limit, G is the upper limit.

if d4<f4 then disp (f4-d4), if d4 >g4 then disp (d4-g4)

Data (d4) is 1.8.  Lower limit (f4) value is 2, upper limit (f6) value is 6.

Thanks.



Thanks for your example but it appeared to work in one direction only.

Answer (score 0):

I tried but it only works in one direction whether which number is larger than the other.

I was more interested in something like this. Excuse crude example..

[image]